# Grouping, yet concatenating values from within the group in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MySQL table as such:

```
| CUST_ID | VISIT | PROD_ID |
|---------|-------|---------|
| 1       | 1     | 3473    |
| 1       | 2     | 324     |
| 1       | 2     | 324     |
| 2       | 1     | 426     |
| 2       | 2     | 4418    |
| 3       | 1     | 4523    |
| 4       | 1     | 976     |
| 4       | 1     | 86      |
| 4       | 2     | 3140    |
| 4       | 3     | 1013    |
```

And I would like to transform it to this:

```
| CUST_ID | VISIT | PROD_IDs |
|---------|-------|----------|
| 1       | 1     | 3473     |
| 1       | 2     | 324, 324 |
| 2       | 1     | 426      |
| 2       | 2     | 4418     |
| 3       | 1     | 4523     |
| 4       | 1     | 976, 86  |
| 4       | 2     | 3140     |
| 4       | 3     | 1013     |
```

This is kinda an ugly hack, I get it.

I have no idea how to cleanly create such a thing. I've tried a variety of unsuccessful grouping strategies. Even a clue or hint in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to group by cust_id + visit, then you can do that and use a `GROUP CONCAT` on the PROD_ID field, for example:

```
SELECT
    CUST_ID, 
    VISIT, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(PROD_ID) PROD_IDS
FROM
    table
GROUP BY 
    CUST_ID,
    VISIT
```

Reference: [GROUP CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Holy smokes! I hadn't discovered `GROUP_CONCAT` before. This is exactly what I needed. BAM!

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck cool, also if you want to get distinct values, you can do `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT prod_id)`